# Random numbers in a while loop

Tags: java, eclipse, random

I am working on a project with Java using Eclipse IDE. Now, what I want to achieve is I want 3 different random numbers which will be generated using Random() function. I want them to be between 0 and 3 values which include 0, 1 and 2. I have this small algorithm to generate each one differently.

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
    rand1=rnd.nextInt(3);
    rand2=rand1;
    rand3=rand1;
    while(rand2==rand1){
        rand2=rnd.nextInt(3);
    }
    while(rand3==rand1){
        rand3=rnd.nextInt(3);
    }
```

But at the moment, my code still generates values like (1, 0, 0) or (2, 1, 1). I could not find why, thanks for all your help.

Comment: You need `while(rand3 == rand1 || rand3 ==rand2)` for the second while loop, otherwise the third number can equal the second like your examples do. Actually, why not just set the third one to be the one that isn't the first or second one?

Answer (score 1):

You can just place all possible values in one list, shuffle it with `Collections.shuffle(list);` and read first `n` values you need.

Answer (score 1):

The code there does not fit your specifications. The first loop will terminate when rand2 != rand1 and the second loop will terminate when rand3 != rand1.

The triple (1,0,0) satisfies these conditions, as 1 != 0 and 1 != 0 ( the same goes for (2,2,2)). You probably want an extra condition there, to ensure rand3 != rand2:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
rand1=rnd.nextInt(3);
rand2=rand1;
rand3=rand1;
while(rand2==rand1){
    rand2=rnd.nextInt(3);
}
while(rand3==rand1 || rand3 == rand2){
    rand3=rnd.nextInt(3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This because you check that the second and third random number is just different from the first one. You don't check if rand2 and rand3 are different too.
You can edit the last while this way:

```
while(rand3==rand1 || rand3 == rand2){
    rand3=rnd.nextInt(3);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't check whether rand2 and rand3 are equal or not. Also if the three random numbers shouldn't equal each other, you can let the second number choose between the last two possibilities and force the third to the one value left. Technically it is POSSIBLE, that your code doesn't come to an end. ;)

Answer (score -1):

You don't really want random numbers - what you really want here is to randomly return one of the six permutations

- 0, 1, 2
- 0, 2, 1
- 1, 0, 2
- 1, 2, 0
- 2, 0, 1
- 2, 1, 0